# "Attempt to call private method" with depot tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

"Attempt to call private method" with depot tutorial

In my "cart.rb" model I have

```
def add_product(product_id) 
  current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first 
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
  else
    current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id=>product_id)
    line_items << current_item
  end
  current_item
end
```

And in "line_items_controller.rb" I have

```
  def create 
    @cart = find_or_create_cart 
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) 
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
  .....
```

When I select an item to add it to the cart I get a "Attempt to call private method" error.

Application trace is

```
/Users/machinename/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:236:in `method_missing'
/Users/machinename/Documents/rails_projects/depot/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

I saw some discussion of an error similar and it sounded like the answer was upgrade to ruby 1.9 (I am using 1.8.7). Is that the answer or is there another possible cause of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give all the code of cart.rb if possible.maybe your add_product method is under some private method like. I know this should be comment i want to explain it with example so i paste it in answer.

```
 private
   def self.some_method
     #some code 
   end

   def add_product(product_id)
```

your code from the comment is look like following

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy 
end #this end is creating problem

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first 
    if current_item 
      current_item.quantity += 1 
    else 
      current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id=>product_id)
      line_items << current_item 
    end 
    current_item 
  end
```

you add your method after closing the class. put end of class after the end of method and i bet it will work.

change cart.rb to

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy 


  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first 
    if current_item 
      current_item.quantity += 1 
    else 
      current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id=>product_id)
      line_items << current_item 
    end 
    current_item 
  end 

end #this end should after the end of class method
```

Comment: class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
end

def add_product(product_id) 
  current_item = line_items.where(:product_id => product_id).first 
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
  else
    current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id=>product_id)
    line_items << current_item
  end
  current_item
end

Comment: you add your method after closing the class. put end of class after the end of method and i bet it will work.